# FileNotFoundException NetBeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans

I am new to programing, I'm taking CSE 205, this class is asking me to use NetBeans for my projects...

I'm supposed to read from a file and write the contents to a new file. The program I wrote works in visual studio, but It gives me the FileNotFoundException in NetBeans. Both files, my main and the file to be read are in the same folder. is it my NetBeans settings?

Comment: More information is needed. Update your question to show your code that is reading and writing the files, and the stack trace for the `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first you try to put absolute path while initializing object File or writing/reading from file with other methods. If I want to use only name for reading/writing file without defining path to it, I put it in root directory of project. For example:

- **project_name**

  - dist
  - nbproject
  - src
  - test
  - **myfile.txt**